# My css files (i.e. including bootstrap which i through CDN) is suddenly stopped working on production server

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I recently uploaded my laravel project to a production server using Namecheap; everything was working okay... So, I decided to make a couple of changes to my CSS file, but suddenly my styles stopped rendering. I have reverted the changes but it still doesn't work.
Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Without any information e.g. a live domain we cant really help. I mean something I can guess is that you are requesting http files over https or vice versa?

Comment: @MichaelMano no error was outputted. It just stopped working.

Comment: so developer tools returns no errors? or no php error.

Comment: @MichaelMano yes it doesn't.

Comment: Did you make sure, your assets are linked properly in your source code and the files are accessible? Did you try accessing your css directly in the browser?

Comment: Yes, I did. And it showed up.

Comment: I have fixed it. I had to restore my previous backup. Everything works fine now. Thanks guys.